# jquery 'change' event is not working in IE

Tags: jquery

Yes, I know it doesn't work in IE and using 'click' works. But here is my problem.

I have two select boxes - Country and City. 
Selecting a country populates the city select box (and updates a google map).

The following code works like a charm in IE and Opera:

```
  if (jQuery('#city').length > 0) {
    jQuery('#city').change(function(){ populateCityListBox(); });
  }
```

If I use 'click' instead of 'change', then the populateCityListBox() is triggered once when I click the select box arrow, and one more time when I click the list box element.

How can I avoid this double triggering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the fact that IE doesn't fire the change event until the element loses focus.

A simple solution might be to keep track of the last value of the select, and only allow the function to execute if it is different.

Also, just a side note, in your `change` callback, you don't need to wrap it in an anonymous function if all you are doing is calling it.

```
jQuery('#city').change(populateCityListBox);
```

works just the same as what you have there.

Comment: I have a select that works just fine with .change in IE8 and IE7(Compat) without losing focus.

Comment: @Steven, there's no magic    $("#id-selector").change(function);   as was stated by TM

Comment: @Marc: Sorry, just misread :)
@TM: Brilliant. This works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this might work (not tested though):

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
  var interval = 50;
  var changeHack = 'change-hac';
  var select = $("#viewByOrg");
  select.data(changeHack) = select.val();
  var checkVal=function() {
    var oldVal = select.data(changeHack);
    var newVal = select.val();
    if (oldVal !== newVal) {
      select.data(changeHack, newVal);
      select.trigger('change')
    }
    setTimeout(changeHack, interval);
  }
  setTimeout(changeHack, interval);
}
```

play with the interval to suite your feelings.
also - if the trigger('change') trick won't work, try calling your onchange method there directly